# I can't resolve how to stop request after 401 , used interceptors axios

Tags: javascript, axios

```js
const setInterceptors = (api, authStore) => {
  const Unauthorized = 401;
  const Forbidden = 403;
  const Error = 404;
  const ErrorServer = 500;
  let isRefreshed = false;
  let refreshQueue = [];
  const processQueue = async () => {
    while (refreshQueue.length > 0) {
      const queuedRequest = refreshQueue.shift();
      try {
        const response = await api(queuedRequest.config);
        queuedRequest.resolve(response);
      } catch (error) {
        queuedRequest.reject(error);
      }
    }
  };

  api.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      if (authStore.tokens.accessToken) {
        config.headers["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer " + authStore.tokens.accessToken;
      }
      console.log("request");
      // if(isRefreshed){
      //   debugger
      // }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error),
  );

  api.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      console.log("response");
      return response;
    },
    async (error) => {
      const { config, response } = error;
      if (response && response.status === Unauthorized) {
        if (!config.isRetry) {
          config.isRetry = true;
          try {
            if (!isRefreshed) {
              isRefreshed = true;
              await authStore.refresh();
              processQueue();
              return api(config);
            } else {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                refreshQueue.push({ config, resolve, reject });
              });
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, "catch retry");
          }
        }
      } else if (response && response.status === Forbidden) {
        console.log("forbidden");
      } else if (response && response.status === Error) {
        console.log("404");
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );
};

export default setInterceptors;
```

API was standard axios, authStore -> pinia

I don't know how to stop multiplying requests after take 401 error.
I have 4 requests and 1 response --> after this I can block request, but it doesn't make sense.

I want to take first 401 error, and stop requests

Request books--> in component

[image]

I searched through the documentation but still don't understand how to do it